# Oddities in runtime evaluation of static variable initializers when debugging

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, runtime

My App was running fine when I started it from inside Visual Studio with the debugger attached (F5). But when I started the App without attaching the debugger (Ctrl-F5 or starting the .exe file) i did always get a `StackOverflowException` which was luckily logged in the Windows event logs.

The problematic code was the following:

```
namespace Caliburn.Micro.Contrib
{
    public static class FrameworkExtensions
    {
        public static class ViewLocator
        {
            static readonly Func<string,object, IEnumerable<string>> _baseTransformName = Micro.ViewLocator.TransformName;

            public static void EnableContextFallback()
            {
                Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.TransformName = FallbackNameTransform;
            }    

            static IEnumerable<string> FallbackNameTransform(string typeName, object context)
            {
                var names = _baseTransformName(typeName, context);
                if (context != null)
                {
                    names = names.Union(_baseTransformName(typeName, null));
                }

                return names;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I called the `FrameworkExtensions.EnableContextFallack()` method during the App startup and the StackOverflowException occured during the first invocation of `Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.TransformName`. This means that the `_baseTransformName` variable is initialized *after* `EnableContextFallback()` was called when no debugger is attached and *before* `EnableContextFallback()` is called when a debugger is attached.

Is was able to fix the bug by adding a static constructor and assign the variable in the constructor

```
namespace Caliburn.Micro.Contrib
{
    public static class FrameworkExtensions
    {
        public static class ViewLocator
        {
            static readonly Func<string, object, IEnumerable<string>> _baseTransformName;

            static ViewLocator()
            {
                 _baseTransformName = Micro.ViewLocator.TransformName;
            }

            public static void EnableContextFallback()
            {
                Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.TransformName = FallbackNameTransform;
            }    

            static IEnumerable<string> FallbackNameTransform(string typeName, object context)
            {
                var names = _baseTransformName(typeName, context);
                if (context != null)
                {
                    names = names.Union(_baseTransformName(typeName, null));
                }

                return names;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This ensures that the variable `_baseTransformName` is always set before the first invocation of `EnableContextFallback()`.

So the question is: Why is there a different initialization behavior for static variables when a debugger is attached and is there a way to "disable" the different behavior?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is: Why is there a different initialization behavior for static variables when a debugger is attached and is there a way to "disable" the different behavior?

Very little is guaranteed about the behaviour of static variable initializers when there's no static constructor. Indeed, you can even create *instances* of classes without the static variable initializers being invoked! When you're using a debugger, the CLR does all kinds of things differently (particularly around JITting).

Using a static constructor is probably the best way of giving you more predictable initialization behaviour.

See my [blog post about type initialization changes in .NET 4](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx) for more information.