# Application won't start when using Caliburn.Micro.Contrib

Tags: c#, caliburn.micro, stack-overflow

I'm developping an application using Caliburn.Micro (v1.5.2) and CMContrib (v1.0.2).
I'm using C# & .NET 4.5.

When I launch the application within VS 2012, i've got no problem, but when executing the .exe directly from Windows Explorer, the application won't start.

I've take a look at the events observer and I've got something that i can't really understand:

```
Récipient d’erreurs -474837188, type 5
Nom d’événement : CLR20r3
Réponse : Non disponible
ID de CAB : 0

Signature du problème : 
P1 : txsgui.exe
P2 : 1.0.0.0
P3 : 521daac1
P4 : Caliburn.Micro.Contrib
P5 : 1.0.2.0
P6 : 521da9dd
P7 : 86
P8 : 0
P9 : System.StackOverflowException
P10 :
```

I can understand that the problem come from the CMContrib library, that this lib making a StackOverFlow exception, but i've got no context when this is happening.

Thx for you help.

Comment: When you launch the application from VS 2012 in debug-mode you don't get any problems at all, not even binding exceptions ?

Comment: nop, the main view is displayed, and the dialogbox (from CMContrib) are working well. The strange thing is, if I remove all the references from CMContrib, its NLog which cause me trouble. If I remove both everything is perfect.

Comment: Have you tried to run the application on a different system than yours ?

Comment: I haven't try that...i'll git it a shoot as soon as i can.

Comment: Do that because this is pretty weird.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue.
I am using VS2010, Caliburn Micro ver 1.3.1.0 and Caliburn.Micro.Contrib ver 1.0.1.0 
Windows7 64 bit

```
Fault bucket 3956564328, type 5
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: mcsp.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5271fea4
P4: Caliburn.Micro.Contrib
P5: 1.0.1.0
P6: 4f85ce36
P7: 1e7
P8: 0
P9: System.StackOverflowException
P10:
```

Found an entry here:
[Oddities in runtime evaluation of static variable initializers when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385504/oddities-in-runtime-evaluation-of-static-variable-initializers-when-debugging)

I will do a bit of digging to see whether it will solve this issue.